# How do I remove the "required" from submission

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to remove the "required" attribute from the [mf gig calendar plug-in](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mf-gig-calendar/).

Tried several things - the most basic of which was to turn

```
required = ["title", "start_date"];
```

into

```
required = [""];
```

or just erasing the line itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you write some code? I have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: I can't add tags yet, but I'm guessing you're referring to http://wordpress.org/plugins/mf-gig-calendar/

Comment: Can I email you the file? Can't send you a link to the url - it gives me a 404 for locking invaders out.

Comment: You can see the code here: http://albany.craigslist.org/cpg/4361826961.html